# OpenGL zoom efficiency

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, zooming

I am a beginner with OpenGL and as my first application I tried to to generate a fractal using the method of barycentric subdivision of a triangle. Not knowing the functions of OpenGL for perspective change, my first idea of a zoom and change of viewpoint algorithm was to simply redraw the entire fractal with different starting point coordinates and scaling factor every time a key is pressed (arrows for camera movement and +/- for zoom).

Given the fact that for 6 iterations of barycentric subdivision about 56 000 triangles are drawn (6^0+6^1+6^2+6^3+6^4+6^5+6^6 triangles) this algorithm is very inefficient. So I tried to use the gluPerspective() for zooming, the result was sadly a black screen, instead of a fractal. I have two main questions:

- Does OpenGL functions for perspective change and viewpoint ( gluPerspective(), gluLookAt(), glFrustum(), etc) redraw the entire figure with different coordinates, or use more efficient methods of obtaining the same result? Will their use be more efficient in my case?
- What did I do wrong in my code. Why am i getting a black screen?

  ```
  #include <GL/glfw.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <math.h>

  using namespace std;

  struct punct{ GLdouble x, y;}; //"punct" means "point" in my native language
  punct A, B, C;
  int n=0, mode=1;
  double l=1.6, ox=0, oy=0, scale=1;

  punct mid (punct A, punct B);
  void initiate ();
  void line (punct A, punct B);
  void triangle (punct A, punct B, punct C);
  void divide (punct A, punct B, punct C,int i);

  int main ()
  {
      int     width, height;
      bool    running = true;
      char input=NULL;

      glfwInit();

      if( !glfwOpenWindow( 800, 800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_FULLSCREEN ) )
      {
          glfwTerminate();
          return 0;
      }

      glfwSetWindowTitle("Baricentric");

      while(running)
      {
          glfwGetWindowSize( &width, &height );
          height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

          glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

          glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
          glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

          //This functions make my screen black 
          //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
          //glLoadIdentity();
          //gluPerspective (50*scale, width/height, 10.0, 100.0); 

          initiate ();

          if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_KP_ADD) && glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_LCTRL)) input='+';
          if(!glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_KP_ADD) && input=='+') {
          if(n<7) n++;
          input='\n';
          }
          if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_KP_SUBTRACT) && glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_LCTRL)) input='-';
          if(!glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_KP_SUBTRACT) && input=='-') {
              if(n>0)n--;
              input='\n';
          }

          if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_KP_1)||glfwGetKey('1')) input='1';
          if(!glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_KP_1) && input=='1') {
              mode=1;
              input='\n';
          }

          if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_KP_0)||glfwGetKey('0')) input='0';
          if(!glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_KP_0) && input=='0') {
              mode=0;
              input='\n';
          }

          if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_KP_ADD) && !glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_LCTRL)) l+=0.002*(n+0.5); //'l' is replaced with 'scale' when using gluPerspective()
          if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_KP_SUBTRACT) && !glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_LCTRL)) l-=0.002*(n+0.5); //'l' is replaced with 'scale' when using gluPerspective()
          if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_UP)) oy-=0.002*(n+0.5);
          if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_DOWN)) oy+=0.002*(n+0.5);
          if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_RIGHT)) ox+=0.002*(n+0.5);
          if(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_LEFT)) ox-=0.002*(n+0.5);


          if (n) divide (A,B,C,1);


          glfwSwapBuffers();

          running = !glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED);
      }

      glfwTerminate();

      return 0;
  }

  punct mid (punct A, punct B) {
      punct C;
      C.x=(A.x+B.x)/2;
      C.y=(A.y+B.y)/2;
      return C;
  }

  void initiate () {

      A.x = -(l/2)+ox; A.y = -(l*sqrt(3)/4)+oy;
      B.x = l/2+ox; B.y = A.y;
      C.x = 0+ox; C.y = (l*sqrt(3)/4)+oy;

      glBegin (GL_QUADS);
          glColor3f(0.93,0.84,0.82); glVertex3d(-1, 1, 0);
          glColor3f(0.01,0.95,0.83); glVertex3d(-1, -1, 0);
          glColor3f(0.80,0.71,0.80); glVertex3d(1, -1, 0);
          glColor3f(0.8,1,0.8); glVertex3d(1, 1, 0);
      glEnd ();

      glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
          glColor3f(0,0.6,0.88); glVertex3d(C.x, C.y, 0);
          glColor3f(0,0.77,0.73); glVertex3d(B.x, B.y, 0);
          glColor3f(0.01,0.66,0.62); glVertex3d(A.x, A.y, 0);
      glEnd ();

      if (mode==0) {
          glLineWidth (0.1);
          glColor3f(0,0,0.36);
          glBegin (GL_LINE_LOOP);
              glVertex3d(C.x, C.y, 0);
              glVertex3d(B.x, B.y, 0);
              glVertex3d(A.x, A.y, 0);
          glEnd ();
      }
  }


  void divide (punct A, punct B, punct C, int i) {
      if(i<=n) {
          punct a, b, c, G;
          c=mid(A,B);
          b=mid(A,C);
          a=mid(B,C);
          G.x=(A.x+B.x+C.x)/3;
          G.y=(A.y+B.y+C.y)/3;
          if(mode==1) {
              triangle(G,a,C);
              triangle(G,b,C);
              triangle(G,a,B);
              triangle(G,c,B);
              triangle(G,c,A);
              triangle(G,b,A);
          }
          line(c,C);
          line(a,A);
          line(b,B);
          divide(G,a,C,i+1);
          divide(G,b,C,i+1);
          divide(G,a,B,i+1);
          divide(G,c,B,i+1);
          divide(G,c,A,i+1);
          divide(G,b,A,i+1);
      }

  }

  void line (punct A, punct B) {
      glBegin (GL_LINE_STRIP);
          glVertex3d(A.x,A.y,0);
          glVertex3d(B.x,B.y,0);
      glEnd ();
  }

  void triangle (punct A, punct B, punct C) {
      glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
          glColor3f(0,0.6,0.88); glVertex3d(C.x, C.y, 0);
          glColor3f(0,0.77,0.73); glVertex3d(B.x, B.y, 0);
          glColor3f(0.01,0.66,0.62); glVertex3d(A.x, A.y, 0);
      glEnd ();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so many before, you've fallen for the misconception of thinking OpenGL was a scene graph. This is not the case.

OpenGL is a drawing API. Your OS provides a canvas (window, PBuffer, Pixmap, etc.) and OpenGL provides the drawing tools in form of points, lines or triangles.

> Does OpenGL functions for perspective change and viewpoint ( gluPerspective(), gluLookAt(), glFrustum(), etc) redraw the entire figure with different coordinates,

All they do is change the values of a few matrices. Nothing on the screen is changed by this. You have to redraw the whole thing to make a visible change.